# How to add a grain type look to background-color

Tags: css, html, colors, background-color

Notice the blue sidebar has a grain effect added to it.

How to I achieve this **without using an image**?

[image]

Comment: Use a background image.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a textured image with only a few colours to achieve a grain effect.  As a GIF or similar, it will only amount to a few hundred bytes if you do it right.  That is, make a small image and tile it.

If you want to find out how a specific site achieved that effect, use a DOM inspector to check the code behind the element.  Chrome has this functionality built-in if you right click and choose "Inspect Element".  I bet you'll find there's a background image.

Comment: Ah, I see you have edited your question now to state that you don't want to use an image.  I will delete my answer if it is not helpful to you.

Comment: You sir are correct. I just found their background image http://www.gannett-cdn.com/static/images/patterns/noise.png?1363187788